# how use R to find the start and end of the largest continuous sequence for each ID?

Tags: r

I have a data set. Each ID has a sequence of either 0 and 1, a column of date and another column of num.day. I would like to find the start and end of the longest 1 sequence for each ID. Then calculate the date gap between start to end. After that add the end date's corresponding num.day.

For example, the following table ID = 1, the longest sequence start with date 4 (one record above) and end with 9. So the gap is 5. The add the end dates's corresponding num.day should be **day_gap** = (9-4) +3 = 8. If one ID has multiple sequences have the same longest length, then take the max **day_gap** of these sequences for this ID.

[image]

Here is the code to create the dummy table

```
library(data.table)

ID=c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10))
set.seed(1)
fill=sample(c(0,1),length(ID),replace=TRUE)

dat=data.table(ID,fill)[,date:=seq(.N),by="ID"][date==1,fill:=0]
set.seed(1)
dat$num.days=sample(1:10,nrow(dat),replace=TRUE)
```

Comment: not possible to reproduce sample date without `set.seed()` used...

Comment: sure. I have added that

Comment: What should happen when (within the same ID) multiple groups have the same (maximum) length?

Comment: I have added the comment to the initial question. If that is the case, the take the max of the gap (=datediff + num.day) as the ID's gap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution with dplyr:

```
dat %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 mutate(group = cumsum(fill != lag(fill, default = fill[[1]])) + 1) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 filter(fill == 1) %>% 
 group_by(ID, group) %>% 
 mutate(fill_group_no_max = max(row_number())) %>% 
 ungroup() %>% 
 group_by(ID) %>% 
 filter(fill_group_no_max == max(fill_group_no_max),
        group == max(group)) %>% 
 summarise(dategap = max(date) - min(date) + last(num.days)) %>% 
 ungroup()
```

Update: Sorry! I forgot the summarise part

Comment: I might be wrong, but I don't think your code does what the OP requested. The output for `ID =1` should be 9-5+7=11. I don't see how to get this from the output. Can you elaborate? What code did you use to generate `dat`?

Answer (score 0):

An option using `base::rle` in `data.table`:

```
dat[, {
        r <- rle(fill)
        i <- which.max(r$lengths * r$values)
        .(day_gap = r$lengths[i] + num.days[sum(r$lengths[1L:i])])
    }, ID]
```

output:

```
   ID day_gap
1:  1      11
2:  2      12
3:  3       8
```

data:

```
library(data.table)

ID = c(rep(1,10),rep(2,10),rep(3,10))
set.seed(1)
fill = sample(c(0,1),length(ID),replace=TRUE)

dat = data.table(ID,fill)[,date:=seq(.N),by="ID"][date==1,fill:=0]
set.seed(1)
dat$num.days=sample(1:10,nrow(dat),replace=TRUE)
dat
```

`dat`:

```
    ID fill date num.days
 1:  1    0    1        3
 2:  1    0    2        4
 3:  1    1    3        6
 4:  1    1    4       10
 5:  1    0    5        3
 6:  1    1    6        9
 7:  1    1    7       10
 8:  1    1    8        7
 9:  1    1    9        7
10:  1    0   10        1
11:  2    0    1        3
12:  2    0    2        2
13:  2    1    3        7
14:  2    0    4        4
15:  2    1    5        8
16:  2    0    6        5
17:  2    1    7        8
18:  2    1    8       10
19:  2    0    9        4
20:  2    1   10        8
21:  3    0    1       10
22:  3    0    2        3
23:  3    1    3        7
24:  3    0    4        2
25:  3    0    5        3
26:  3    0    6        4
27:  3    0    7        1
28:  3    0    8        4
29:  3    1    9        9
30:  3    0   10        4
    ID fill date num.days
```